# How to add context menu to Finder to run a shell script

Tags: macos, shell, automator

I have a shell script that takes two arguments, 1) full file path 2)file name.
How can use Automator to add context menu to Finder to run the shell script with chosen file path and file name as arguments.

Comment: I found that another item may meet your need: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215287/adding-a-script-to-macos-finder-contextual-menu/12584114#12584114

Answer (score 1):

In Automator create a new Service, then choose Run Shell Script and just Save you Service. That is it. 
Also you can read next post [Mac OS X services with Automator and shell scripting](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2011/03/howto-build-mac-os-x-services-with-automator-and-shell-scripting.ars)