# Add submenu in context menu Osx

Tags: macos, contextmenu

I try to integrate my Software in Mac so i want to add actions in the Finder ContextMenu.

For the moment i have an entry "MySoftware" that launch and shell script via automator script using this thread:

[Stackoverflow adding-a-script-to-macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215287/adding-a-script-to-macos-finder-contextual-menu)

Now i want to do the same but i want 3 actions in 3 sub-menus like:

MySoftware -> update file / MySoftware -> delete file / MySoftware -> openwebsite

But i cannot make this using cocotea or C++ language, only shell script with automator.

Thanks a lot,