# calling a python executable script from apple service created by Automator

Tags: python, macos, shell, applescript, automator

I am trying to add a menu item to launch slideshow from folder right click, so far this is what I have

[image]

I don't think I am doing wrong, the script in directory slideShow/scripts/slideshow is an executable, that has following content:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*-coding: utf8-*-
# file: slideShow


import os
import sys

MODULES_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))), "python")
sys.path.insert(0, MODULES_PATH)

import utils
import slideShow
slideShow.main(utils.ingestData(os.getcwd()))
```

So the question is why does the script from automator manages to write file text555.txt on desktop with correct path but cannot execute the same script?

there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215287/adding-a-script-to-macos-finder-contextual-menu) on stack overflow, but I am trying to launch python script. I tried with replacing scripts/slideshow with python/slideshow.py to make it work with subproces.call(['python', fto]) but that too doesn't work?

I am on Mac OSx 10.7.4.

Comment: Check to see if the path in `fto` is correct. Is `slideshow` a Python script without no `.py` extension? The paths are one difference between it and the desktop file.

Comment: fto path is correct, that's why I am printing it into a text file to check. The script with no .py extension is the one I have pasted at the bottom above, it is executable script with chmod set to +x slideshow

Comment: Did you mark the script as executable? (`chmod +x [script]`)

Comment: I don't think it matters whether the script has been marked with chmod as executable when it's being explicitly passed to python interpreter as an argument. It would matter if you had a `#! /usr/bin/python` line at the beginning of the script and tried to run it directly by name. Maybe you should try that.

Comment: @martineau Oh, right. I had forgotten about that!